# javascript how to "fix" a variable inside a function, through eval?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, eval

I have the following function

```
var label = function() {
  return 'File: '+texts[t];
};
```

which is attached to highcharts, specified here
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.formatter

where `t` has values let's say from 1 to 10 and `text[t]` corresponds to a different text. I attach this function to 10 `highchart tooltips` so that it executes the function with a `mouseOver` event.

The intended logic is that chart 1 has the `text[1]` label appearing, chart 6 has `text[6]`, etc.

The problem is that all charts have the `text[10]` appearing, since `t` has that value when the function is executed.

How can I solve this? Is it a place for `eval()` like

```
var label = function() {
  return 'File: '+eval(texts[t]);
};
```

UPDATE: based on comments, trying

```
var label = function(t) {
  return 'File: '+t+' '+texts[t];
};
```

doesn't work as expected, it prints "File: [object Object] undefined"

Comment: you don't need `eval` for that, just add _t_ as an argument to the function and pass _t_ to it from the loop. ex: `function(t)` and `label(t)`

Comment: The problem you're describing is very common when the variable is accessed though a closure. You need to show the part where `t` is initialized and manipulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common closure problem:

You probably have t in a for loop, just wrap the code which attaches the handler in another function:

```
// This will not work the way you might expect
// The value of i is left at 10 because that is the last 
// time it is changed in the attacheHandlers1 scope held
// but the closure in the anonymous function used as a callback
// in setTimeout
//
function attachHandlers1(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
     setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Version 1", i);
     }, 100)
  }
}

// This works because the value is closured in 
// attachHandlerImpl as 'x' with different values for 
// each invocation
//
function attachHandlers2(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
     attachHandlerImpl(i);
  }
}

function attachHandlerImpl(x){
     setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Version 2", x);
     }, 100);
}

attachHandlers1();

attachHandlers2();
```

Will output:

```
Version 1 10
Version 1 10
Version 1 10
Version 1 10
Version 1 10
Version 1 10
Version 1 10
Version 1 10
Version 1 10
Version 1 10
Version 2 0
Version 2 1
Version 2 2
Version 2 3
Version 2 4
Version 2 5
Version 2 6
Version 2 7
Version 2 8
Version 2 9
```

Comment: While the explanation is excellent, this doesn't seem to be compatible with highcharts since nothing appears. It seems like highcharts "protects" its code against calling other functions (the same happens when I try eval)

Comment: In detail, the message is: TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context. at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:3:14) at Object.InjectedScript.callFunctionOn (<anonymous>:750:66)

Comment: I see that I have to implement this by using pre-established variables in highcharts. The spirit of the question is in any case very well answered in your post, so I give it as the valid solution. Thanks!

Comment: Your comment: var label = function(t) {
  return 'File: '+t+' '+texts[t];
};
doesn't work as expected, it prints "File: [object Object] undefined" suggests that t is not an integer, try console.log(t)

Comment: It is an integer, but highcharts transforms this somehow. I have solved it by storing the variable t in the "series" space (highcharts), which then I can retrieve through this.series.userOptions.(variable). But this is rather not a question of javascript but of highcharts API (even though it is javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the rest of your implementation details, something like this could work:

```
var texts = ['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3']
var label = function(idx) {
  return "File: " + texts[idx];
};
```

`label(2)` returns "File: Text 3"

Comment: Question edited to add more details. I have tried this suggestion (equal to Neal's one) but it is not working, I assume because of highcharts implementation (?)

Comment: Please show how you are populating the value of the texts array. Your edited example makes it seem like you're passing in an object, not an index.